# Can I make my Apache server simply return an HTTP OK when it receives a POST command?

Tags: python, apache

I have an Apache server running on my desktop. If I put

```
192.168.0.84
```

into a broswer, it serves what is in `index.html` in

```
/var/www/html
```

When a remote machine sends a `POST` to /records, I would like this server to send back an `HTTP OK` to keep the sending machine happy. It doesn't need to do anything else with it really.

Is this an easy thing to do? Can I just run a wee python script for example to achieve this? If so, how do I make the Apache server do this?

I'm writing some code for an OS on a little ARM device that is successfully sending a POST to my desktop, but the sending thread is hanging as it's not getting a response from my machine and I just need to avoid this happening. In the field it will be talking to a specialist piece of kit that will process the information it sends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an empty file named `records` near your `index.html` and apache will respond with `200 OK` for any valid request to `/records`.

Comment: Work a treat, can't believe it was that simple! Thanks!